# Аргумент base равен 0 для функции int

Tags: python, python-3.x

Аргумент `base` для функции `int()` может быть равен 0, что это за система исчисления?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Применение параметра `base=0` можно понимать как **автоматический выбор**

- одного из параметров `base=2`, `base=8`, `base=10`, `base=16`,
- на основе **формы первого параметра**.

---

*Примечание:*

Первый параметр функции-конструктора `int()` может начинаться с пробелов и/или табуляторов, после которых может быть еще символ `+` или `-`.

Они для автоматического выбора не важны — анализ начинается *после них.*

---

*Алгорифм:*

1. Если первым символом является **нуль** (`0`), то следующим символом должен быть один из

   - `b` или `B` (binary, двоичная), тогда применяется `base=2`,
   - `o` или `O` (octal, восьмеричная), тогда применяется `base=8`,
   - `x` или `X` (hexadecimal, шестнадцатеричная), тогда применяется `base=16`,

   иначе возникает ошибка.
2. Если первым символом является **ненулевая** десятичная цифра,

   - тогда применяется `base=10`.
3. Иначе возникает ошибка.

---

Сравните:

```
int( "17")            # 17
int( "17",  10)       # 17
int( "17",  16)       # 23 (= 1*16 + 7)
int( "17",   0)       # 17

int( "017", 10)       # 17
int( "017",  0)       #    ошибка - после нуля в начале должно быть b, B, o, O, x или X

int(  "11")           # 11
int(  "11",  2)       #  3 (= 1*2 + 1)
int("0b11",  2)       #  3
int("0b11",  0)       #  3  - автоматически int("0b11", 2)

int(  "17")           # 17
int(  "17",  2)       #    ошибка - цифры 7 нет в двоичной системе
int(  "17",  8)       # 15 (= 1*8 + 7)
int("0x17",  8)       #    ошибка - 0x17 не является восьмеричным числом из-за 0x в начале
int("0x17",  0)       # 23 (= 1*16 + 7) - автоматически int("0x17", 16)
```

Answer (score 7):

В Python, когда база аргументов для функции int() равна 0, это интерпретируется как механизм «автоматического обнаружения». Функция попытается определить основание передаваемого числа на основе префикса строкового представления этого числа. Если строка начинается с «0x», число считается шестнадцатеричным (по основанию 16), если оно начинается с «0o», число считается восьмеричным (по основанию 8), а если оно начинается с «0b ", число считается двоичным (с основанием 2). Если строка начинается с любой другой цифры или если она начинается с «0», но не имеет префикса, функция будет считать, что число является десятичным (с основанием 10).